# Branched Code And Conflicting Assembly Versions....How To Deal With This?

Tags: .net

I really hope this makes sense.  I've tried just about everything I can think of, without any luck.

Here's my situation:

There used to be a single code base that several teams were contributing to...but the goals and focuses of the teams started to diverge.  Many months ago, it was decided to branch the code.

Version A
Version B

The thing is, while A and B are now different, after months of independent changes - they still share a LOT of logic, and, more relevant to my problem, class/interface/object names and namesspaces.

I work with Version A.  We're trying to leverage something inside of Version B.  Version B wrote this very complex, difficult, time consuming thing that uses external libraries - but is now working great

It sounded easy.  Version B has a project that encapsulates all this logic and all I need to do is add a reference to their assembly (.dll).  But there assembly is dependent of lots of other projects found in Version B - that are *ALSO* in Version A - but it fails due to the numerous differences in A and B.  For example, the Version B dll I add expects iInterface1 to have String X - but in Version A there is an iInterface1 in the same namespace - but it already has an Enum X.

All of the DLLs end up getting copied to the /bin folder - I can't find a way to encapsulate one version to be used by Project B's assembly.  I've tried listening to the AssemblyResolve event and directing it to a subfolder in /bin - but I can't understand how that will help me.  Once I resolve the assembly once, it won't fire again, but I would need to redirect it more than once.

Adding them both to the GAC is not an option; but I think that might be the only reasonable way to do it.

Can anyone give me some direction?  Would ILMerge be something I could use here?

Comment: I feel your pain, bro. Branching is the first step on the road to hell.

Comment: after branching you better say your daily prayer. and no, git won't help you. neither will hg. you're dooooomed. i doubt you'll get to a *clean* solution (assemblyresolve stuff gives me cold shudder and the GAC isnt much better) unless you refactor version A and version B until you can extract the code you want to reuse into a new project X. then you'll have to maintain project X such that it stays usable for both version A and version B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you load assembly B into a separate AppDomain (with the files stored in a different directory) and then make calls into the AppDomain from your main app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was the best route to go or not; but ultimately we ended up using WCF to allow the two processes to communicate with one another - named pipes on the same box.  This avoided the assembly versioning issue completely.